# How can I use FnMut with generic parameters in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to define a FnMut signature to allow library users to pass a closure as a callback. The closure will be boxed and stored in a struct.

The callback will be given certain input parameters, and must return a struct that implements a trait.

Currently, the signature is defined as:

```
    new_request_session_callback: Option<
        Box<
            dyn FnMut(
                    my::Parameters
                ) -> OutputSessionStruct
                + 'static,
        >,
```

I would like to modify this signature so that it will accept any output struct that implements a particular SessionTrait. How can I do this?

Comment: How about `-> dyn SessionTrait`? Since the actual return type can't be static in that situation, you will need dynamic dispatch for the return type of the closure as well.

Comment: As a side note, `+ 'static` is redundant. It's the default in this situation anyway,.

Comment: Shoud of course be `-> Box<dyn SessionTrait>`.